# Apply automated line wrap in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, newline, word-wrap

I'm currently writing my master thesis using Texlipse. Eclipse provides me with automated line wrapping which is nice. However I frequently run in the following problem. Let's say this is some text in my editor:

```
Line 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Line 2: consetetur sadipscing elitr,
Line 3: sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
Line 4: invidunt ut labore et dolore 
Line 5: magna aliquyam erat, sed 
Line 6: diam voluptua.
```

Now I will add just a few words ("clita kasd gubergren") in line 1:

```
Line 1: Lorem ipsum clita kasd gubergren
Line 2: dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr,
Line 3: sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
Line 4: invidunt ut labore et dolore 
Line 5: magna aliquyam erat, sed 
Line 6: diam voluptua.
```

What happes is, that automatic line wrapping will throw the words "dolor sit amet" into line 2. However line wrapping is NOT triggered in line 2.
I can trigger the newline by adding and removing a space in line 2. But then the problem moves to line 3. I for sure can proceed until the end of the paragraph. But this happens quite often and by time drives me nuts.

**Is there any shortcut?** Eg: Selecting the paragraph, hitting STR+Magic and everything gets rearranged?

Comment: Check the `Save Actions` in `Preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a party working solution. When hitting the very counter intuitive shortcut ESC+Q the line wrapping will be applied. However the text will be shiftet to the very left, killing all your tabulars. However it is easier to Hit the shortcut followed by a few tabulars rather than adding a space in each line.